# AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility - root not bracketed issue in QuantLib/R

Tags: options, quantlib

I'm trying to compute an implied volatility -- I am trying to match real data I see in Yahoo finance which shows an IV of about 27%. My call in 'R' for the same params returns a root not bracketed error -- can anyone help pls?

Sample:

```
> AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility(type="put", value=2.7, 
      underlying=55.0, strike=60, dividendYield=0.02, riskFreeRate=0.03, 
      maturity=0.02, volatility=0.2)

RESULT:
Error in americanOptionImpliedVolatilityEngine(type, value, underlying,  
: root not bracketed: f[1e-07,4] -> [2.300000e+00,1.256782e+01]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a simple root finder, and if you give it impossible starting values... well then it fails.  Here, you can play with the values and it seems bounded at USD 5 whereas you start from USD 2.7:

```
R> AmericanOption(type="put", underlying = 55, strike = 60, 
+                 dividendYield = 0.02, riskFreeRate = 0.03, 
+                 maturity = 0.02, volatility = 0.2)
Concise summary of valuation for AmericanOption 
 value  delta  gamma   vega  theta    rho divRho 
     5     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 
R>
```

Maybe you had strike and underlying mixed up?

```
R> AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility(type="put", value=2.7, 
+              underlying=60.0, strike=55.0, dividendYield=0.02, 
+              riskFreeRate=0.03, maturity=0.02, volatility=0.2)
[1] 1.48203
attr(,"class")
[1] "AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility" "ImpliedVolatility"  
R>
```

Comment: Yes. There's no way that a put option with underlying at 55 and strike at 60 has a value of 2.7.  It has to be worth at least 5, because that's what you would gain by exercising now.

Comment: That helps -- thanks. But let's try to look at a specific example as I'm still stuck trying to match what Yahoo shows:

`code
From Yahoo -- today -- an MSFT 40 PUT, for July 15, 2016 has the following (bid=0.38, ask=0.40) - IV = 31.86%

`code > AmericanOptionImpliedVolatility(type="put", value=0.39, underlying=55.48, strike=40, dividendYield=0.00, riskFreeRate=0.01, maturity=0.53, volatility=0.2)
[1] 0.3224758
attr(,"class")

' So this matches.